# Java split based exact regex that matched

Tags: java, regex, split

So I have this code for demonstration purposes:

```
    String input = "abcRANDOM STRINGabc";

    String arr[] = input.split("abc");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // output: [, RANDOM STRING]

    arr = input.split("(?=(abc))|(?<=(abc))");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // output: [abc, RANDOM STRING, abc]

    arr = input.split("(?=([abc]+))|(?<=([abc]+))");// wrong syntax
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // output: [a, b, c, RANDOM STRING, a, b, c]
```

First one will split on exact match of "abc" but not return the match which results in an empty cell.

Second one will split on exact match of "abc" but not lose the match.

I want a modified version of the third one or something completely different that works that will not lose an indefinite amount of an [abc] sequence.

for example if I had this String "aaaaabbRANDOMSTRINGabcabc"
expected output: [aaaaabb, RANDOMSTRING, abcabc]

Comment: "I want a modified version of the third one or something completely different that works that will not lose an indefinite amount of an [abc] sequence." Ok. We are not a regular expression factory. Do some research and use one of the many regex tools available to develop one that meets your needs. My favorite is regexpal.com

Comment: You can use `(?=(?=[abc])a*b*c*)` and just remove the first empty cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
String input = "aaaaabbRANDOMSTRINGabcabc";
String arr[] = input.split("(?<=[abc])(?![abc])|(?<![abc])(?=[abc])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// output: [aaaaabb, RANDOMSTRING, abcabc]
```

You are splitting in a point such that:

- it is preceded by `[abc]` and it is not followed by `[abc]` or
- it is not preceded by `[abc]` and it is followed by `[abc]`.

Comment: Using `(?<=[abc])(?=[^abc])|(?<=[^abc])(?=[abc])`, you don't need to remove the empty strings.

Comment: @ctwheels You don't need to do it in any case

Comment: True, but that matches 2 fewer locations and improves performance. On the given string using my regex above uses `197` steps as opposed to `223` with yours.